# How to make tkinter.Menu focused?

Tags: python, tkinter

I make a hot key (Alt+s) to make a Menu button active.

Here is my code.

```
MenuBar = tkinter.Menu(Win)
StartMenu = tkinter.Menu(MenuBar)
StartMenu.add_command(label="Action 1",command=ActionOne)
StartMenu.add_command(label="Action 2",command=ActionTwo)
MenuBar.add_cascade(label="Start",menu=StartMenu)
```

I bind a event to make StartMenu focused.

So I use

```
Win.bind_all("<Alt-s>",lambda event: StartMenu.focus())
```

It doesn't work.

And focus_force() doesn't work,too.(I don't know whether it work,But it have nothing changed)

```
Win.bind_all("<Alt-s>",lambda event: StartMenu.focus_force())
```

Comment: when you say it doesn't work, does that mean it's not getting focus or that it's not opening up? Just giving it focus isn't enough to open the menu. How are you determining it's not getting focus?

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks,What I want to do is when I press ``alt+s``,And Menu could be opened.So I use ``.focus()``.Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: In your case, pressing `Alt-s` should show the `StartMenu` because its label is `Start` (the first charater is 'S').  So no need to bind the key.

Comment: I think you are using Linux, right? Then try `MenuBar.add_cascade(label="Start",menu=StartMenu, underline=0)` and try again.

Comment: @acw1668 Wow,I know,it can achieve if ``label="start"``,But what if ``label`` is not English word but other language?Can I set another word to do this instead of the first character?

Comment: Set `underline=n` where n is the index of character in the menu string.